# Unobtrusive validation: Regex validation of optional field

Tags: jquery, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using MVC data annotations to specify a validation regular expression for a field on my model. The field is optional, i.e. it does not have the `[Required]` attribute applied:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+$")]
public int Quantity { get; set; }
```

When client-side validation runs, this field is not validated against the regex. Looking at the code in jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js it becomes clear why:

```
$jQval.addMethod("regex", function (value, element, params) {
    var match;
    if (this.optional(element)) {    // <- returns if field is optional
        return true;
    }

    match = new RegExp(params).exec(value);
    return (match && (match.index === 0) && (match[0].length === value.length));
});
```

How can I add validation so that an empty field is allowed, but if a value is entered, it must match the regex?

On edit: Obviously I could just change the code in jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js, but I'd rather leave this file alone so that my changes don't get overwritten by future updates.

Comment: it should allow if the field is empty because of the `if (this.optional(element)) {`  condition

Comment: @Arun P Johny: exactly. How can I change that (while leaving the code in jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js alone)?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m8J8H/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is incorrect. `d+` means "Match one or more decimal digits". Change your data annotation to this (note the `*` in place of the `+`, which means "zero or more times"):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d*$")]
public int Quantity { get; set; }
```

Check out [this Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: That doesn't make any difference because the validation function exits before it even looks at the actual regex due to the `if (this.optional(element)) { ... }` line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `[Required]` attribute to make the value not optional, and use a regex that allows an empty string by changing the `+` (*one or more*) with `*` (*zero or more*):

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^\d*$")]
```